# How to get the outline of an irregular image as Bezier Path in iOS

Tags: ios, text, uiimage, uibezierpath

I'm doing some text layout development in iOS, and I found out that the Text Container has a property exclusionPaths to support text layouts like in pages. But here I need a bezier path of the image, if I have an irregular image, how can I get the outline of the image as a bezier path? Just like the butterfly in the [link](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/text-kit-ios-7/).

```
UIBezierPath *exclusion = *ButterflyBezierPath*;

self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusion];
```

Thanks!

Comment: what have you done so far to define a random exclusive path?

Comment: Actually I've just done some basic exclusion paths for now, like a circle or an oval. I have not figure out how to deal with the sophisticated graph with transparent background yet. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to study and go throw below links it will helps you out:

**1)** http://www.objc.io/issue-5/getting-to-know-textkit.html

**2)**     https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

**3)**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html

Comment: The references you provided are very helpful, but I still cannot deal with the problem. I just want to get the path of the opaque part of a half-transparent image. I googled that but found nothing...